# Android drawable folder naming convention

Tags: android, naming-conventions

I want to create a drawable folder for layout-sw320dp only.

I got `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi` and `drawable-xhdpi`.

How to name it?

Comment: Naming without typo is best -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple. Just create one more folder inside `res` and give it a name `drawable-sw320dp`.